# Firefox's about:config for Safari

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I'm testing an extension that was developed for a Safari browser.  Reseting Safari data doesn't clear the data saved by the extension (like username and password), nor does uninstalling it.

So I'm looking for Safaris configuration options.  Essentially what is Safari's equivalent to Firefox's "about:config"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension "likely" saves its data inside `~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage/` inside a file named: `safari-extension_com.XXX.YYY` , where XXX.YYY differs pending on the name of the extension. If you delete that file, it'll kill all of its settings, which should re-populate to the defaults when re-launched. Ensure you've quit Safari before deleting.

Comment: oops. bounty expired while i was on vacation. sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

Advanced options in safari:
http://itc.virginia.edu/network/proxy/safari.html

But maybe you could ask in superuser look at this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/236558/how-to-clear-all-html5-local-storage-from-safari

This should work it's very weird that those credentials don't get deleted:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/apple/clear-all-browsing-history-in-safari/

http://www.techgainer.com/clear-remove-browser-data-history-passwords-firefox-ie-safari-chrome-opera/